# Using signed certificates with OpenSSH on Windows - converting .pem to ecdsa

Tags: ssh, openssl

I'm trying to set up a SFTP server on Windows. I have successfully installed OpenSSH as per https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server.

My clients are complaining that they have to accept a self-signed key to connect. This is pretty normal to me but is it possible to use a public CA signed key? To avoid this problem?

I've obtained a set of `.pem` certs from letsencrypt. How can I convert them to `ssh_host_key` and `ssh_host_ecdsa_key` format?

Comment: [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) uses SSH keys.  [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) uses TLS certificates, such as your Letsencrypt one.  They are different.

Comment: I understand the difference between SFTP and FTPS. I need SFTP but I want to used signed certificates, so that the clients don't have to manually accept them. Is this possible?

Comment: There is https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30396/how-to-set-up-openssh-to-use-x509-pki-for-authentication which discusses X509 certificates for SSH.  The developer's site (linked) doesn't mention SCP or SFTP, so it's unlikely, as the client software would need to be modified to use X509 certificates instead of SSH keys.  I might be wrong though :-)

Comment: Did you get any solution on this one? I know its a few years ago. By I want the same as you beskribe.